# Programación funcional

Tags: java

**Hola me pueden ayudar con esto por favor, tengo el código pero me salen error**

Dentro de las estructuras de datos muchos lenguajes de programación poseen varios tipos de estructuras pre-construidas que nos ayudan con nuestro trabajo. En Java una de esas estructuras son las Listas (List) que se puede construir de la siguiente manera:

var nums = List.of( 3, 9, 7, 12, 20, 4, 11, 9, 21, 6, 8, 10 );
Otro elemento que se utiliza actualmente es la programación funcional ya que permite realizar muchas operaciones sin la necesidad de estructuras de control como los ciclos repetitivos.

Consulte acerca del uso de programación funcional en listas utilizando Java y desarrolle un programa, en ese lenguaje de programación, que, sin usar ciclos repetitivos, haga lo siguiente sobre la lista nums:

Sumar sus elementos.
Calcular el promedio.
Filtrar aquellos elementos que son menores al promedio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto.

Comment: No añadas código en imágenes, añade código con backticks (`), tres en una línea y tres en otra, añade el código entre el espacio de apertura y cierre.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Adicional a lo que comentan sobre poner el código como texto (para poder replicar tu problema), incluye el mensaje de error completo que encuentras ("me sale error" es cero descriptivo y con el código en una imagen, no hay cómo replicar tu problema). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: El código que muestra la imagen al menos puede observar que tienes problemas más de sintaxis java que de la misma programación. Por ejemplo: para usar ArrayList debes importar java.util.ArrayList, luego en la linea 20 sumaelementos no está definida y si te quieres referir a la variable de la linea 14 el nombre es suma_Elementos pero en la linea 14 no se ve claro que es.  Igual Prom con prom. Java distingue mayuscula de minuscula.